# How to troubleshoot no power in half of mobile home?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

My mobile home isn't getting power to roughly half of it.

When I first lost power I was able to determine it was a bad receptacle because of some melting on the outlet which seemed to have interrupted the current to every outlet and light that was physically past that point. As a quick fix I decided to just bypass the outlet and it restored all functionality for probably 6 months before going out again. I inspected the sight of the original offending outlet and could not visibly determine any damage in the wiring so I replaced that outlet.

These outlets are all connected to a GFCI in the master bathroom on the end of the trailer that was still getting powered. I first tried just resetting the GFCI but the reset button would not press in, so my next thought was to replace that GFCI which had the same result, unable to reset.

Any guesses on what I might be dealing with here?

I'm assuming this a short occurring somewhere and am wondering if, where it appears to have downed all other power receptacles past the originally affected outlet, if the short would have to be either between that outlet and the next in line or on whatever wire(s) is connecting that circuit to the GFCI on the other side of the trailer, or if it could be shorting and any one of the outlets or light sockets anywhere in the circuit.

I will also note that any inspections of the wires on the originally affected outlet were minimally invasive. I.E. No drywall was cut back and I was only able to observe the section of wire easily inspectable.

[image]

Comment: Usually the power comes from the panel to the problem, and no power after that.  It is possible to have multiple problems, but rarer.   Melting is a problem that usually requires more than a quick fix/bypass.  If hot enough to melt an outlet/plug then hot enough to melt wire insulation inside of walls.

Comment: I see. So do you think that would be somewhere between the panel and the GFCI, or between the panel and the originally melted outlet. I have a pretty primative understanding to how its actually all run. Any speculation on what may be the cause of it melting in the first place? I have an idea it could have been rodent related somewhere on the wire, but thats purely a guess. I drew and added a small diagram just now, forgive my artistry.

Comment: It's either a loose connection at the last working outlet (the connection to the wiring to the first outlet that doesn't work), or in the wiring between them (it could be that something chewed through the wires), or a loose connection at the first non-working outlet. You'll have to inspect to see. Start by shutting off the power, then look at each outlet invovled.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your time. I guess my next question would be do you think the outlet first in line would be the culprit, or could it possibly be one further down the line shorting and tripping the GFCI and cutting power to the other outlets in line before it? Edit: Oh okay I misread that at first, that would be why I need to inspect the other outlets. Could it also be a wire leading into the first bad outlet coming from the other end of the home?

Comment: I only ask because I dont know quite enough to know if all outlets are run in a single "looped circuit" or if they could possibly be run independently. Ive been trying to put away for an Electrician but times are tough.

Comment: Also, for the hell of it I tried using a voltage tester on the first dead outlet and it was reading no power, but I guessed that was maybe because the connected GFCI wouldn't reset, interrupting the current, or is that even how that works?

Comment: GFCI’s won’t reset without power, in the US we Daisy chain not loop, big difference as loops are used in other parts of the world.

Comment: Probably another bad outlet.  Not all outlet failures are melty-smoky, actually most fail without incident.

Comment: Alright guys thanks for the input! So the new gfci outlet has a display light so I think its getting power to it, but I revisted the replaced breaker (tandem breaker) and saw that it would only reset on the top and not the bottom. Every thing on the effected part of the trailer is on that breaker.

Comment: Could a short be responsible for the GFCI and the breaker malfunction simultaneously?

Comment: Sounds like the breaker failed also, will need to replace it.  It usually is a simple job with the power/main breaker off.  If it is a rental, you must contact landlord who must get an electrician to replace.

Comment: So do you think that leads us to a short somewhere? We replaced the breaker during the early troubleshooting but the bottom switch just springs back instantly.

Comment: And a far as the malfunctioning GFCI, when it was all working properly and tripping in the past, I only ever notice it disabling outlets in the two bathrooms, it never effected the light or anything, so I'm wondering if that may actual be a separate issue pertaining to

Comment: A few outlets that would have already been disabled by whatever is causing the breaker to fail

Comment: Thank you to everyone for your input, its greatly appreciated! Extension cords have become the main theme of my home, and I'm sick of it, so any information I can soak up is a major benefit.